# Locating an element in bs4

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

Trying to scrape all the information of every item dozer on this page.
I have just started and have only fair idea about scraping but not sure of how to doing that.

```
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.rbauction.com/dozers?keywords=&category=21261693092')    
soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')

#trying all d/f ways buh getting oly nonetype or no element
get= soup.findAll('div' , attrs={'class' : 'sc-gisBJw eHFfwj'})
get2= soup.findAll('div' , attrs={'id' : 'searchResultsList'})
get3= soup.find('div.searchResultsList').find_all('a')
```

I have to get into each class/id and loop a['href'] and get information of each dozer.
Please help.

Comment: what is the issue that you are facing

Comment: @Preethi Can you update the question with exactly which _information of every item dozer on this page_ you are looking for? Please [edit the question](/posts/54938817/edit) to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the data you are looking for to load before reading it into 
the BeautifulSoup object. Use [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html) in selenium to wait for the page to load as it takes a while to render fully:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.rbauction.com/dozers?keywords=&category=21261693092')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'searchResultsList')))
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
```

This line should return the hrefs from the page then:

```
hrefs = [el.attrs.get('href') for el in soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'searchResultsList'}).find_all('a')]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help! but this is giving me all links in a list. I actually wanted to get into each link(all_links) and bring its product details. This was helpful though. Please help

Comment: for loop in all_links:
    loop.click()
    break                                                      I get each link and click on that link get product info.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use requests

```
import requests 
headers = {'Referrer':'https://www.rbauction.com/dozers?keywords=&category=21261693092'}
data = requests.get('https://www.rbauction.com/rba-msapi/search?keywords=&searchParams=%7B%22category%22%3A%2221261693092%22%7D&page=0&maxCount=48&trackingType=2&withResults=true&withFacets=true&withBreadcrumbs=true&catalog=ci&locale=en_US', headers = headers).json()

for item in data['response']['results']:
    print(item['name'],item['url'])
```